# SQL CASE statement in JOIN - when value in other table exists

Tags: sql, select, db2, case

I have table T1

```
TICKETID
1
2
```

I have table T2

```
  ID  TICKETID   STATUS
  1   1          NEW 
  2   1          OPEN
  3   1          CLOSED
  4   2          NEW
  5   2          OPEN
  6   2          RETURNED
```

I want to select from T1 and do the JOIN with T2 and if status of the record was ever in status RETURNED then I need to have a value "YES" else I need to have value "NO"

So final result should be

```
  TICKETID RETURNED_FLAG
   1        NO
   2        YES
```

I tried something like this but I am not sure if this is optimal or even correct.

```
    SELECT T1.TICKETID, CASE (T2.ID) 
    WHEN NULL THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'YES' 
    END  FROM T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.TICKETID=T2.TICKETID AND T2.STATUS='RETURNED'
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 1):

Close.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT T1.TICKETID,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(T2.ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as flag
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.TICKETID = T2.TICKETID AND T2.STATUS = 'RETURNED'
GROUP BY T1.TICKETID;
```

A more typical way would be:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t2
                          where t2.ticketid = t.ticketid and t2.status = 'RETURNED'
                         )
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flag
from t1;
```

This should have better performance, particularly with an index on `t2(ticketid, status)`.

Answer (score 1):

If every ticket could only be returned once you could also use DECODE without grouping:

```
SELECT T1.TICKETID,
    DECODE(T2.STATUS, 'RETURNED','YES','NO') as flag
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
ON T1.TICKETID = T2.TICKETID AND T2.STATUS = 'RETURNED';
```

If a ticket would have multiple RETURNED entries in T2 this would result in multiple YES lines for that ticket.

Comment: best proposition for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TICKETID, 
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP(1) 'YES' 
               FROM T2 
               WHERE T1.TICKETID=T2.TICKETID AND T2.STATUS='STATUS'),
              'NO') AS RETURN_FLAG
FROM T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is correct but not your case utilisation and you should add distinct for remove duplicate:

```
SELECT distinct T1.TICKETID, 
CASE WHEN T2.ID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END  FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.TICKETID=T2.TICKETID AND T2.STATUS='RETURNED'
```

Multiple methods here are good too, but for me, stay simple.